# tar changing files

Tags: file, tar

I am tar-ing a directory containing a thousands of file. Files get created and deleted (but never updated) several times per seconds, and taring the directory takes about a minute.

Anybody knows what guarantee I have on the files that will be archived? Can I get half-written files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can *definitely* get half-written files.

One common solution is to not write files to a location (and/or name) where they are expected to be correct. You could instead write them to some temporary directory (and/or name) *on the same volume/filesystem* and when they are done move/rename them to the correct directory/name.

The reason they must be on the same filesystem is easy: only this way can a move be done atomically: i.e. the very first moment the file is visible under the "final" name it will already be written completely.